# Differential system, a matrix with eigenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Let's say that we have $n$ differential equations written in the form: $x'(t) = Ax(t) + v \exp(\lambda t)$, where $v$ is the eigenvector of $A$ such that $A v = \lambda v$ and $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix.
Assume that $A$ has $n$ linear independent eigenvectors (and $n$ pairwise different eigenvalues).

Show that there is no vector $a \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $\psi(t) = a \exp(\lambda t)$ is a solution, but $\psi(t) = a\exp(\lambda t) + bt\exp(\lambda t)$ for some values $a, b \in \mathbb R^n$ is a solution.

I'm not sure if I have to show that every solution of my system is of the given form OR if there is at least one solution (for particular $a$ and $b$).

What have I tried?

$$a\lambda \exp(\lambda t) + b \exp(\lambda t) + b t \lambda \exp(\lambda t) = A(a\exp(\lambda t) + bt\exp(\lambda t))+ v \exp(\lambda t).$$
This is equivalent to
$$(a \lambda + b) + t \cdot b\lambda = (Aa + v) + t \cdot Ab,$$
so $Ab = b\lambda$ (and this implies $b = k \cdot v$ for real $k$) and $a \lambda + b = Aa + v$, but how to proceed now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have: $(A-\lambda)a = (k-1)v$.

Now, $\psi(t) = a \exp(\lambda t)$, $\psi'(t) = a \lambda \exp(\lambda t)$, we have: $ \lambda a \ne Aa + v \ \forall a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, so for any vector $a\in R^n$:

$(A-\lambda)a \ne -v$, so $k-1\ne -1$, i.e $k\ne 0$.

So you found yourself suitable $a,b$, $b =kv , k \ne 0$, $a$ satisfies: $(A-\lambda)a = (k-1)v$.